# Cannot define user defined literals

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

I was reading about user-defined literals, and I came across this snippet, but I got compiler error when I tried to use it.

```
int operator ""_fix(long double d)
{
     // returns d as a 1.15.16 fixed point number
     return (int)(d*65536.0f);
}
```

It says Error : Expected an operator. I am on Visual STudio 2013, which I believe has good support for C++ 11. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: [VS13 doesn't support user-defined literals.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/06/28/cpp-conformance-roadmap.aspx

Comment: VS 14 CTP [does support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/11/c-11-14-feature-tables-for-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx) it, if you're brave enough to install it.

Comment: @Praetorian Is there any info about when the stable release for VS 14 is coming out?

Comment: I think I remember reading last quarter of this year, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score -2):

Remember that there must be a space after `""` and before the suffix. 
So you should write:

```
int operator "" _fix(long double d)
{ // ...
```

Comment: This is not true, and doesn't answer the question.